# Grails GORM-force an update statement even if GORM doesn't think the instance is dirty

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I've run into a situation where GORM doesn't detect that an object has changed and so neither fails nor generates a sql UPDATE statement. In other words:

```
 //by the time I get here, it doesn't do anything good or bad
 team.save(failOnError:true, flush:true)
 //doesn't throw an error, doesn't log an UPDATE statement
```

Is there a way to force GORM to run an update statement regardless of whether it *thinks* an instance needs updating?

Answer (score 0):

This happens if values are set when an instance is not attached to a hibernate session or when it is in read only mode. If you set properties on such an instance and later decide to save it, you can do this:

```
  <A Domain Csass nam reference here>.withSession{session->
      if(!item.isAttached()){
           item.attach();
      }
      else if(session.isReadOnly(item)){
            session.setReadOnly(item,false)
       }
        item.properties=item.properties // force gorm to see changed properties; comes with data binding overhead though
       item.save(failOnError:true)//should generate update now
  }
```

Comment: Note that this solution does not address "Is there a way to force GORM to run an update statement regardless of whether it thinks an instance needs updating?", this solution helps avoid some scenarios where an instance has changed and GORM doesn't "know" it has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
team.markDirty()
team.save()
```